# Is there a standard definition of what 'heresy' is across Protestant denominations?

Tags: protestantism, terminology, heresy

Different major branches of Christianity often understand certain terms differently. Is there a standard definition of 'heresy' across major Protestant denominations?

Comment: Just a thought, but you might take a Christian creed, such as the Apostles' Creed, and simply contradict every statement in the creed in order to determine what heresy is across Protestant denominations. You may not end up with a nice neat definition of what constitutes heresy, but you would have some, uh, constituents. For example, "I believe in God the Father Almighty, maker of heaven and earth" would become "God is neither a father nor is he almighty." ". . . who was born of the virgin Mary" becomes, "Mary was impregnated by her fiance Joseph." ". . . he will come to judge the living

Comment: and the dead" becomes "Jesus will not return to earth from heaven." "I believe in the holy catholic church" becomes "Christianity is so hopelessly divided that there is no such thing as a universal church. let alone an undivided church." I'm sure you get the idea. Don

Comment: @rhetorician Thanks for this - it would be interesting if the Apostles' Creed was the standard!

Comment: @one Interesting?! It will be 'the standard' one day (again)!

Answer (score 2):

I believe C. Matthew McMahon’s definition [here](https://www.apuritansmind.com/historical-theology/heresy-in-the-church/) accurately sums up the majority view (emphasis mine):

> Heresy is an erroneous or false opinion, repugnant unto and *subverting the doctrine of faith* revealed in the Word as *necessary unto salvation*; and obstinately maintained and perniciously adhered unto by a professed Christian.

By that definition, true heresy not just an erroneous or unscriptural system of belief, but a belief system that denies a doctrine that is *essential to salvation*, and is therefore damning.

The primary biblical example is the “circumcision party” mentioned in [Galatians 2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Galatians%202&version=NKJV&interface=amp), who taught that salvation was available only to those who kept the entire Mosaic Law over and above having faith in Christ. This is heresy because it denies that faith alone in Christ alone is *all* that is necessary to justify believers (cf. [Galatians 2:15-16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Galatians%202%3A15-16&version=NKJV&interface=amp).) Paul pronounced these teachers *anathema* (meaning “accursed” or “damned”) because they were preaching “a gospel contrary to the one we” (that is, the Apostles) “preached to you” ([Galatians 1:8, ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Galatians%201%3A8&version=ESV&interface=amp).)

Another example would be Hymenaeus and Philetus, mentioned in [2 Timothy 2:17-18](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Timothy%202%3A17-18&version=NKJV&interface=amp). They were “upsetting the faith of some” by teaching that the resurrection had already happened (spiritually). This is heresy because it denies a bodily resurrection.

**EDIT:** Which Christian doctrines are “essential to salvation” and which are not? You will get varying answers from Protestants. Unfortunately, a large part of that is due to the rise of biblicism, which tends to downplay the very important role that the historic creeds of Christianity play in helping us define and defend biblical orthodoxy. The first seven ecumenical councils were convened to address a number of theological and Christological heresies plaguing the church, including Arianism, Docetism, Apollinarianism, Sabellianism, Nestorianism, and Pelagianism (among others.) The formularies produced by these councils—especially the Apostle’s Creed, the Niceno-Constantinopolitan Creed, and the Definition of Chalcedon—are arguably the best resource for understanding which specific doctrines the Christian church has long considered to be necessary for salvation. These are not meant to add to Scripture or to be equally authoritative with Scripture, but to summarize and defend the clear teaching of Scripture.

As @rhetorician mentioned in the comments section, the Apostle’s Creed is the most fundamental and widely accepted of these. You could view that as the “bare minimum” standard of teaching which a professed believer must affirm in order to be saved. Although not all Protestant denominations would *formally* subscribe to the Apostle’s Creed, in practice it would be hard to find a Protestant church that would take issue with its teaching.

Comment: +1 "subverting the doctrine of faith revealed in the Word as necessary unto salvation" That's interesting - it seems most of the heavy lifting is then left up to defining what is necessary for salvation.

Comment: Given that there is no single definition adhered to by all Protestants, offering that "majority view" is helpful. Let's hope most Protestants still go by what the NT says. Jesus identified some who were the custodians of orthodox Jewish teaching as making their converts twice as much subjects for hell than themselves (Matt.ch.23). Paul's anathema covers all teaching/practice that does not deliver people from the deadly grip of a devilish world, which the pure gospel of Christ alone frees us from. The Bible is clear as to what is necessary for salvation.

Comment: @Anne Do you think there is a majority view among Protestants re what is necessary for salvation?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather I updated the post to address some of the comments asking which doctrines would be considered essential to salvation. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: @andrewtc  Your Edit is helpful. Just to mention that anyone professing acceptance of the beliefs in the Apostles' Creed would be acknowledged as an orthodoxly Christian believer, but mere verbal profession of any creed cannot save anybody! Many Protestant denominations who are clear about that (though their numbers seem to diminish every year - can't give a percentage figure for that) do agree totally with the Apostles' Creed. Others that seem to attach salvation to joining their group and doing what their leaders state - don't. Telling.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather On that count, broadly, yes. Faith in Jesus Christ as the resurrected Son of God who takes away our sins. Arminians, Anglicans, Calvinists, we all believe in the free gift of salvation by grace, through faith. As a member of a couple of parachurch Protestant organisations, I think you'd have 99% agreement on the Apostles Creed, and 90% on Nicene, excepting the line about baptism, maybe. But then the devil would be in the subsequent details. I'm excluding liberals as I don't consider them Protestants or even Christians.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean an enumeration rather than a definition, right?

If the definition is 'that which contradicts true church teaching', then, as who is in the church is only known for sure to God, then the enumeration is uncertain.

If the definition is 'that contrary to the Word of God and prejudicial to salvation', then doctrinal disputes over what the Bible says and over salvation makes the enumeration uncertain.

The good news is, like in matters pertaining to who is in the church, the Holy Spirit is a good and reliable guide, and 90% of us will agree on 90% of heresies.

Comment: +1 for posting an answer and listing 2 possibilities. "I assume you mean an enumeration rather than a definition, right?" An enumeration might be what's important. If you think it's enumerating various things, then yes, please go ahead and do that.

Comment: I don't have much to add on the enumeration front except to say deviations from Apostles Creed and the Nicene (excepting the line about baptism, maybe) would almost universally be considered heresy. But that's still not an enumeration because there are always new heresies. "Jesus wants you to violently attack all sinners", or "There are subsequent revelations constituting scripture after the NT" doesn't contradict the Creeds but I'd consider it heresy.